# Using JRuby and MRI for a common app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, jruby, bundle

I need to use both JRuby and MRI for my rails app.

Here's the scenario -

My app uses a background server which handles a lot of threads. I'm having performance
issue with running it on MRI. The background server is started with a `rake` task and needs 
to use the Rails environment.

I'm using Passenger for the Web Server. Since JRuby support for Passenger is quite recent,
I would like to go with using MRI.

Here's something I want -

This uses Ruby 1.9 to start the server :

`sudo passenger start -p 80 -e production --user=deploy`

and within the same app, this runs the background server -

`jruby -S rake background_server:start_daemon RAILS_ENV=production`

The problem is, the second command `jruby -S rake` asks for rebundling the app.

Is there any way I can get this in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in the same app. you'll need separate applications that run under different rubies if you want this to happen. in SOA architecture, you'd send a message to your background server for it to process a job.

So, in heroku you'd create one application for your web running in MRI; then you'd create an application in JRuby for your background processes. They'd communicate via a shared Redis or shared database.

I would recommend using Trinidad or Puma and keeping it all in JRuby though (as opposed to keep running passenger); it'll be a much simpler architecture.